# How do I use the featured image of another page in a post in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy page `taxonomoy-$slug.php` and I want to be able to display the featured image of another page on it. Is there any way to do this without plugins?

Comment: You might do better at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: will try there, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place your page ID static into a variable, just like the below code:

```
<?php 
$post_id = 12;      //place here your page id  
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ); 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id ); ?>
```

Now, place this $image variable inside the  tag:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
```

I hope, this may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can from but you need to get ID of that page.

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full' );
```

This function get you a featured image of the page where you should have an ID of the particular page you want to get it from. You can also pass which image size you want.

For more information : [get_the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)

Hope this information will help you.